# enterprise search center unavailable when installing sharepoint 2010 in stand alone mode

Tags: enterprise-search

I'm running a w2008r2x64 vm where I have a fresh install of sharepoint 2010. The install was "farm" then "stand alone"

When I enter the site (set up as a Team Site) and tries to create a new site, choosing either enterprise search center or fast search senter, I get an error:

An unexpected error has occured.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be hard to answer you like that, with so few informations.

Please could you log in the central administration, and control that the SharePoint Server Search service is started on the server, if not activate it.

Then, control that you have a running Search Service Application in the Service Applications.

If all these points are ok, try to control the logs in the 14, and read the full error.

Comment: Application managment -> Server applications -> Manage Services on server -> sharepoint server search : started
Application managment -> Server applications -> serach service application -> "online for crawling" Under topology there are "admin" and "databases" (3 lines)

Comment: Found an error in the log: Publishing Feature activation failed. Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature must be activated at the site collection level before the Publishing feature can be activated. Doing this solved it.